# I want to create pagination style using GWT same as SMARTGWT

Tags: gwt, pagination, smartgit

I want to create pagination style using GWT same as SMARTGWT.
I am little bit weak with HTML and CSS. How can I add images like http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/#remotePagingGrid .

Please HELP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT already has pretty nice paging functionallity for it's CellList. Check it out here: [GWT CwCellTable](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable). 
If setup correctly it works out of the box without any CSS or HTML kowelege.